# How to add Space or new line in hero card of bot framework

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to create boarding pass using hero card instead of facebook template. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: talk more details please, what you already try? what do you already Researched?

Answer (score 0):

BotFramework uses Markdown. To represent a paragraph break you need to have a blank line (i.e. "\n\n").  However, some channels do not allow for carriage returns in the Title and SubTitle fields.

Markdown like this:

```
This is paragraph one

This is 
paragraph two
```

Will be rendered as

```
This is paragraph one 
This is paragraph two
```

See documentation at: http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-content/#markdown-paragraphs